# sort a file basis on key and group by datacenter

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a file like this `key=value` and I want to sort it basis on key in ascending order. I have two types of machine - one in abc datacenter and othern in pqr datacenter.

```
p10=machineA.abc.host.com
p7=machineB.abc.host.com
p3=machineC.abc.host.com
p8=machineD.abc.host.com
p10=machineE.pqr.host.com
p7=machineF.pqr.host.com
p3=machineG.pqr.host.com
p8=machineH.pqr.host.com
```

So I should have something like this printed out group by datacenter and sorted in ascending order by key. Is this possible to do by any chance?

```
p3=machineC.abc.host.com
p7=machineB.abc.host.com
p8=machineD.abc.host.com
p10=machineA.abc.host.com

p3=machineG.pqr.host.com
p7=machineF.pqr.host.com
p8=machineH.pqr.host.com
p10=machineE.pqr.host.com
```

I tried `sort -n machines.txt` but it's not the way I want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`sort`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
sort -t'.' -k2 -k1,1V file | awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="." }dc && $2 != dc{ print "" }{ dc = $2 }1'
```

- `-t'.'` - field separator
- `-k2` - sort by *datacenter* name at 1st stage
- `-k1,1V` - natural sort of *keys*

---

*Update*:

Considering *datacenter* name as the 3rd field from the end:

```
awk -F'[=.]' '{ $0 = $1 OFS $(NF-2) OFS $0 }1' machines.txt \
| sort -k2,2 -k1,1V \
| awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="." }{ sub(/^[^ ]+ [^ ]+ /, "") }dc && $2 != dc{ print "" }{ dc = $2 }1'
```

The output:

```
p3=machineC.abc.host.com
p7=machineB.abc.host.com
p8=machineD.abc.host.com
p10=machineA.abc.host.com

p3=machineG.pqr.host.com
p7=machineF.pqr.host.com
p8=machineH.pqr.host.com
p10=machineE.pqr.host.com
```

Comment: nice approach.. I have one quick question though. Is there any way to pick dc index from the end. I mean -3 is the index for dc from the end instead of using 2 from the starting? Because I have some hostname in which dc is at 2nd index and some at 3rd index but they all have dc at -3 from the end so thats why I want to pick dc from the end.

Comment: @user5447339 Yes, you can write `$(NF-2)` instead of `$2` in the awk script.

Comment: @mwp I tried that as well and that didn't worked either.

Comment: @downvoter, before clicking "somewhere" down - you would better see that this approach do works and gives the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest here is the version I am using `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040`

Comment: In my case, I want to pick dc from the end which is -3. Is this possible?

Comment: @user5447339, with `sort` tool you can not sort by relative/abstract field number. I could suggest some working trick but without group separator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169835/discussion-between-user5447339-and-romanperekhrest).

Comment: @user5447339, got a complete solution. See my update

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/g' inputfile | sort -t. -k2 -k1,1n | sed 's/^/p/g'
```

This will set `.` as the field separator. Then it will sort textually the second field  (`-k2`) and then sort numerically the first field (`-k1`).

Comment: Is there any way to pick dc index from the end. I mean -3 is the index for dc from the end instead of using 2 from the starting? Because I have some hostname in which dc is at 2nd index and some at 3rd index but they all have dc at -3 index from the end so thats why I want to pick dc from the end.

Comment: The `-k` option of `sort` wont take negative arguments. However you can use `rev`. For example if you want to sort by the 3rd index from the end do: `rev inputfile | sort -t. -k3 | rev`

Comment: I see.. make sense now. Where I need to feed this `rev inputfile | sort -t. -k3 | rev` in your above command? You mean something like this `sed s/.\(.*\)/\1/g inputfile | rev inputfile | sort -t. -k3 | rev -k1,1n | sed s/^/p/g`

Comment: I tried this `sed s/.\(.*\)/\1/g machines.txt | rev | sort -t. -k3 | rev -k1,1n | sed s/^/p/g` but it gives me invalid option error as `rev: invalid option -- 'k'
Usage: rev [options] [file ...]`

Comment: This will sort the lines according to the 3rd field from the end: `sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/g' 50032310.in | rev | sort -t. -k3 | rev | sed 's/^/p/g'`